# How can we replace all the matching special characters in the string except the first one?

Tags: php

This is my data variable.

```
$data = "• Rohit • Mohit • Khusi";
```

I am looking for the output as below

```
-Rohit<br/>
-Mohit<br/>
-Khusi.
```

What I tried is

```
str_replace("•", "<br/>-", $data);
```

But I don't want a break line on the top of first string

Comment: A quick (but might not be the cleanest) way could be to only add `<br />` if there's a space before the dot. Something like: `str_replace([" •", "•"], ["<br/>-", "-"], $data);`. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/fLVmk)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: i suggest u to post an answer instead using comment, we can also use simply `ltrim()` , isnt it?

Comment: @devpro - I was thinking about it but since there was a bunch of other answers popping up at the time that solved it just as well (like yours), I thought it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ltrim with that character to trim from left,

```
<?php
$data = "• Rohit • Mohit • Khusi";
echo '-'.str_replace("•", "<br/>-", ltrim($data, '•'));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply @Harish

Answer (score 4):

I would retrieve the names as an array first, then display as wished:

```
$data = '• Rohit • Mohit • Khusi';

$names = preg_split('/\s*•\s*/', $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

foreach ($names as $i => $name) {
  echo '- ', $name, $i === count($names) - 1 ? '.' : '<br/>';
}
```

Alternatively, you could do this after retrieving the names:

```
echo '-', implode('<br/>-', $names), '.';
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/GBa89**

Thanks to @Nick for all the nice suggestions in the comments below.

Comment: You could use the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` option to [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), then you wouldn't need `array_slice`

Comment: @Nick You're absolutely right, always forgetting that flag. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: I'd be inclined to `echo '-' . implode('<br/>-', $names) . '.';` it's a bit cleaner

Comment: @Nick Thought about it, but I'm guessing this is within a template / view (since it's destined to be output) in which case a basic loop seems more appropriate. I'll add it as an alternative. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: That's a fair comment. The loop definitely allows more flexibility to do other things.

Comment: @Nick: what about `ltrim()` with this example?

Comment: @devpro for this specific example it definitely works although my preference is for `preg_split` because you can remove arbitrary spaces and also an array can be more flexible for further processing if it is required. And I have no idea why someone downvoted your answer while leaving the other two similar ones (one of which doesn't even work) untouched...

Comment: @Nick: agreed, this will work for this specific example agreed. yes, and preg_split approach also help for future visitor. thumbs up.

Comment: Thanks for giving your time on my question. It really helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) here to remove first `<br/>` like:

```
$data = "• Rohit • Mohit • Khusi";
$data = str_replace("•", "<br/>-", trim($data));
echo ltrim($data,"<br/>"); // ltrim use here.
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply @devpro

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
echo ltrim(str_replace(".","<br/>-",$data),"</br>");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply @Hasee